# LinearLayout and size of Android UI

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I design a xml( in layout package) in  android project, I want my UI run on any android mobile  and android tablet, if size of device change my UI shows good, I use  LinearLayout for each group, in linearLayout3 I have one textview and one EditText, when I run program I get error from my textview and EditText in linearLayout3,error is:
“Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText”
Please suggest to me a solution for resolving my problem.
Code is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivitytest" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnstop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/r_stop"
            android:text="Stop" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnstart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/r_start"
            android:text="Start" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="150"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Rb_Defualt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:ems="150"
                android:gravity="right" 
                android:text="testdefualt"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Rb_Periodic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="150"
                android:gravity="right" 
                android:text="testperiodic"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Rb_Maual"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="150"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="testmanual"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TxtTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="200"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:text="Please Enter Time"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Txt_Minute_Periodic"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@+id/TxtTime"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:inputType="number" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
      android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/r_ok" 
          android:text="ok" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btn_Config"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/r_config"
          android:text="config" />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnkeyManagment"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
          android:drawableTop="@drawable/r_save"
          android:maxLines="2"
          android:text="key" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: to solve you problem, start by isolating the source of the issue. Apparently, an edit text. start by removing as many elements as possible while still reproducing the problem. That will reduce the amount of code to search for the solution. Then it probably will jump at you.

Answer (score 1):

The android:paddingBottom field in your EditText should be a number and not an id.